# ReactStrap: Accessing the id of the selected dropDownItem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I have this **dropdownList**:

```
  <Dropdown
                  isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen[3]}
                  toggle={() => {
                    this.toggle(3);
                  }}
                >
                  <DropdownToggle className="my-dropdown" caret>
                    {" "}
                    {this.state.dropDownValue}
                  </DropdownToggle>
                  <DropdownMenu>
                    <DropdownItem productid="0">
                      {" "}
                      <div onClick={this.changeValue}>
                        PURE BLACK MAT BLUETOOTH
                      </div>
                    </DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem productid="1">
                      {" "}
                      <div onClick={this.changeValue}>
                        PLAYER BLACK MAT FILAIRE
                      </div>
                    </DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem productid="2">
                      {" "}
                      <div onClick={this.changeValue}>
                        PURE PLUS BLACK MAT MEMORY 128 G
                      </div>
                    </DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem productid="3">
                      {" "}
                      <div onClick={this.changeValue}>
                        PURE LIMITED CHROME GOLD MEMORY 256G
                      </div>
                    </DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem productid="4">
                      {" "}
                      <div onClick={this.changeValue}>
                        PURE GOLD MAT BLUETOOTH
                      </div>
                    </DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem productid="5">
                      {" "}
                      <div onClick={this.changeValue}>
                        PLAYER GOLD MAT FILAIRE
                      </div>
                    </DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem productid="6">
                      {" "}
                      <div onClick={this.changeValue}>
                        PURE PLUS GOLD MAT MEMORY 128 G
                      </div>
                    </DropdownItem>
                    <DropdownItem productid="7">
                      {" "}
                      <div onClick={this.changeValue}>GAME ONE WHITE</div>
                    </DropdownItem>
                  </DropdownMenu>
                </Dropdown>
```

And this **onClickListener**:

```
 changeValue(e) {
    console.log(
      "The selected productId is: ",
      e.currentTarget.getAttribute("productid")
    );
    //The selected productId is:  null
    this.setState({
      dropDownValue: e.currentTarget.textContent
    });
  }
```

I am trying to access the **productid** of the selected **DropdownItem**. But, for some reason the result is always null:

console.log(
      "The selected productId is: ",
      e.currentTarget.getAttribute("productid")
    );
    //The selected productId is:  null

Any idea what I've done wrong?

Comment: Why dont you pass productId as param to changeValue handler ?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi this is the method I've found on SO and it should work. I will try your suggestion though. Thanks.

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi check-out the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364502/how-to-set-selected-item-in-reactstrap-dropdown

Comment: the `DropdownItem` is a react component the `productid` roles as a prop for that reactStrap component, not an HTML attribute, and you cannot access it by `e.currentTarget.getAttribute`

Comment: The example you have posted gets the attribute of `textContent` from a HTML div element not a React component

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi No, check-out the second answer

Comment: Ok, goodluck, hope it works for you

Comment: I have just one question. If I pass the productid as a param to changeValue handler, won't this cause problem with : e.currentTarget.textContent

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I have fixed this by passing the attribute productid inside the div

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by passing the attribute **productid** inside the div:

```
 <DropdownItem>
                      {" "}
                      <div productid="0" onClick={this.changeValue}>
                        PURE BLACK MAT BLUETOOTH
                      </div>
                    </DropdownItem>
```